# How to reserve vertical space for Text in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a `VStack` containing a `Text` and an `Image`. The text contents are loaded asynchronously.

The problem is that if the `Text` is empty it does not take up any space, and everything gets pushed down as soon as the `Text` has its string set. Is there a way to "reserve" this space?

e.g.

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text($viewModel.loadedText)
            Image("myImage")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text is empty then just use a " " string.
so now we have made sure that there always be some text in the Text view.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        let text = viewModel.loadedText.isEmpty ? " " : viewModel.loadedText
        Text(text)
        Image("myImage")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know that your text is always very short (nol longer than 1 line) you could set a fixed height for your text view. Text("").frame(height: 20)

Comment: how can we reserve the space, that we do not know what is yet? so do we have anyway of knowing what string we will get. or do we want to reserve space of the previous loadedText?.